# Proving the differentiablity of a function at the point (0,0)

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $\mathbb{R}^n$ be endowed with a norm $|| \ ||$ and let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function satisfying $|f(x)|\leq||x||^2$ for any $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Show that $f$  is differentiable at the point $0\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

Honestly I have problem with the definition of the derivative of a function of many variables. The definition that I have is the following: The map $f$ is said to be differentible at the point $p\in U\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ if exist a linear map $L:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ such that
$$
\underset{h\to0}{\textrm{Lim}}\dfrac{||{f(a+h)=f(a)-L.h}||}{||h||}=0
$$
From the hypothesis I can see that $f(0)=0$ and so we reduce our limit to
$$
\underset{h\to0}{\textrm{Lim}}\dfrac{||{f(h)-L.h}||}{||h||}=0
$$
I can see also that if I choose $L$ to be the zero map, the last limit is true. Now my problem is if I can choose the map $L$ to be zero at the point $0\in\mathbb{R}^n$ or if there is something I'm not seeing in the definition that allows me to prove that $f$ is differentiable at $0\in\mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: The definition is that some linear map $L$ exists such that ... If you found one, then it exists and everything is fine. (Also there is a typo in the first equation)

Comment: In this context the whole map $L$ should be $0$. For a proof you should write $L=0$ and not that $L$ is a linear map with value $0$ at the point $0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep that's fine. I'd just like to comment on something. It is not that you "choose" $L$ to be the zero map, you $\bf notice$ that $L = 0$, by proving that $$\lim \frac{\|f(h)\|}{\|h\|} = 0$$

which you apparently know how to do.

Answer (score 2):

From what you have found (i.e., $f(0) = 0$) and from the given property of $f$ (i.e., $|f(x)|\leq||x||^2$) we get
$$
\|{f(h)-Lh}\| \le \|f(h)\| + \|Lh \| \le \|h\|^2 + \|Lh \| \\
\frac{\|f(h)-Lh\| }{\|h\|} \le \frac{\|h\|^2 + \|Lh \|}{\|h\|} = \|h\|+\frac{\|Lh \|}{\|h\|}
$$
take the limit of the RHS and set it to zero
$$
\lim_{h \to 0} \bigg(\|h\|+\frac{\|Lh \|}{\|h\|} \bigg) = 0 + \lim_{h \to 0} \left\|L\frac{h }{\|h\|}\right\| \overset{!}{=} 0 \qquad \implies \qquad L = 0
$$